# Creating custom M2 grid and rendering data from a custom table issue

Tags: magento2, grid, di.xml

I tried to follow these tutorials:

- https://medium.com/@jhonkelly2016/how-to-create-admin-grid-in-magento-2-9f39d052322d
- https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html

But in both cases I ended up with a empty page. Without any grid!

This is my controller path: `path/to/vendor/atty31/subscription/Controller/Adminhtml/Subscription/Index.php`. 
    This is my controller content:

```
<?php
namespace Atty31\Subscription\Controller\Adminhtml\Subscription;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory = false;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend((__('View Subscriptions')));

        return $resultPage;
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Atty31_Subscription::subscription_index');
    }
}
```

This is my `di.xml` path: `path/to/vendor/atty31/subscription/etc/di.xml` and it's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Atty31\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">atty31_subscription</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Atty31\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="atty31_subscription_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Atty31\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

and the layout xml path: `/path/to/vendor/atty31/subscription/view/adminhtml/layout/subscription_subscription_index.xml` and it's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="atty31_subscription_grid"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and finally the ui component file's path: `path/to/vendor/atty31/subscription/view/adminhtml/ui_component/atty31_subscription_grid.xml`
and it's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">atty31_subscription_grid.atty31_subscription_grid_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">atty31_subscription_grid.atty31_subscription_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">atty31_subscription_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Blog</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="atty31_subscription_grid_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">atty31_subscription_grid_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">blog_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="atty31_subscription_columns">
        <!--The list of columns-->
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="customer_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Does anybody give some hints what should i check next? or maybe point me to the mistake that i made ?

Thank you in advance!

[UPDATE]
I've added my routes.xml file content:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="subscriptions" frontName="subscriptions">
            <module name="Atty31_Subscription" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my observation (from tutorial you followed), You given front name `atty31_subscription` in `routes.xml`.

So you need to change your xml file name from:

> subscription_subscription_index.xml

to

> atty31_subscription_subscription_index.xml

which is located at: `path/to/vendor/Atty31/Subscription/view/adminhtml/layout/atty31_subscription_subscription_index.xml`

I just tried your code and after change file name, all works fine :)

**Edit I**

In other words, XML file name should be:

```
FrontName_ControllerFolder_ControllerName.xml
```

Comment: Actually my frontname is: `subscriptions`, so if i changed my layput xml file name, like: `subscriptions_subscription_index.xml` , it works :) . Thnx for pointing me to the right direction :) . If you can update your post with this info, will be a good reference for others, as well.

Comment: @AttilaNaghi, Updated :)